# How to select the First output only in this command?

Tags: bash

```
`enter code here`    cat /etc/oratab|grep -v "^#"|grep -v "N$"|grep -v +ASM|cut -f1 -d: -s
PROD

DEV

this command give output to two database and I want to select  only the PROD part  .thankyou for your help!

scripts $  cat /etc/oratab
#



# This file is used by ORACLE utilities.  It is created by root.sh
# and updated by either Database Configuration Assistant while creating
# a database or ASM Configuration Assistant while creating ASM instance.

# A colon, ':', is used as the field terminator.  A new line terminates
# the entry.  Lines beginning with a pound sign, '#', are comments.
#
# Entries are of the form:
#   $ORACLE_SID:$ORACLE_HOME:<N|Y>:
#
# The first and second fields are the system identifier and home
# directory of the database respectively.  The third filed indicates
# to the dbstart utility that the database should , "Y", or should not,
# "N", be brought up at system boot time.
#
# Multiple entries with the same $ORACLE_SID are not allowed.
#
#

PROD:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1:Y

DEV:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1:Y`


    iam trying to automate the database start and stop by writing a shell 
    script and i have two database in server PROD and DEV and the user selects 
    like the script below .
     listdb(){
echo "bases des données dans le serveur   :"
db_list=`cat /etc/oratab|grep -v "^#"|grep -v "N$"|cut -f1 -d: -s`

i=1
for DB in $db_list
do

   echo $i $DB
    i=$(($i+1))
done
read -n1 -p "Select a database to open? [1,2]" doit 
case $doit in  
  1)  startdb() ;; 
  2)  startdb() ;; 
esac
}
```

so I want to pass the name of the database as parameter as the user selects one of them,but this thing i figured  out now(the script above), so i am writing the function to open and stop database.The thing is i dont often use linux so it  am learning it doing this projet.

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please post sample Input of `/etc/oratab` with sample expected output in your post @yonas tek so that we will get better picture of your requirement then.

Comment: `cat /etc/oratab` is an *Unnecessary Use Of* `cat` (a *UUOc*). Simply `grep -v "^#" /etc/oratab | ...` (hint: any time you are using `cat ...` and you are not concatenating two or more files, it's probably a UUOc)

Comment: cat /etc/oratab
basicaly the command above give output to banch of lines and then the two lines below , in which i want to filter only the  names of databases which are PROD and DEV.
PROD:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1:Y
DEV:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1:Y

Comment: @yonastek, comments are not meant for samples, please edit your post and let us know then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `head`:

```
cat /etc/oratab|grep -v "^#"|grep -v "N$"|grep -v +ASM|cut -f1 -d: -s|head -1
```

Comment: We could do this with single `awk` or `sed` we really no need to use these many commands together IMHO.

Comment: thank you so much it works , I am not linux guy and using the command i want to list all the databases in the server , and choose from the list the one you want to open .